# How to get column is Null and condition in php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the table like that

```
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| id | UserID |  ExpDate   | isUsed |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| 1  |  1265  | 2019-09-08 |   0    |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| 2  |  1265  | 2019-08-28 |   0    |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| 3  |  1265  |    null    |   0    |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| 4  |  1265  |    null    |   1    |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
| 5  |  1582  | 2019-09-07 |   0    |
|----|--------|------------|--------|
  .      .          .          .
  .      .          .          .
  .      .          .          .
```

I want to select rows that User = 1265 and isUsed = 0 and ( ExpDate > 2019-09-05 or ExpDate = null)

How to make these selection using laravel eloquent?

I've tried below but it selects all ExpDate is bigger than 2019-09-05 rows on table. Not filtered by UserID

```
       Hak::whereNull('ExpDate')
            ->orWhere('ExpDate', '>', '2019-09-05')
            ->where('UserID', 23)
            ->get()
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with below.

```
Hak::where(function($query){
    $query->whereNull('ExpDate')->orWhere('ExpDate', '>', '2019-09-05');
})->where(['User'=>1265, 'isUsed' => 0])->get();
```

Comment: This helps for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use sub query to achieve this i haven't tested it but you can give it a try.

```
Hak::where('UserID', 23)->where('isUsed', 0)->where(function ($q){
   $q->whereNull('ExpDate')
   ->orWhere('ExpDate', '>', '2019-09-05');        
})->get();
```

Comment: This helps for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think i would write the SQL as followes as `OR` optimizes badly in MySQL.. 
Pretty sure fully supported Parallel Query Execution will change that in the future. 
As they are working on this feature if you want you can read [MySQL 8.0.14: A Road to Parallel Query Execution is Wide Open!](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/)

The SQL result might be wrong as you didn't provide example data and expected result see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing those.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 your_table
WHERE 
   UserID = 23
 AND
   isUsed = 0
 AND
  ExpDate >  '2019-09-05'


UNION ALL

SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 your_table
WHERE 
   UserID = 23
 AND
   isUsed = 0
 AND 
   ExpDate IS NULL
```

**Laravel code**

To warn you i didn't program in Laravel for some time now so this code might be wrong.

```
<?php
 $first = DB::table('your_table')
            ->select('your_table.*')
            ->where('UserID ', '=', 1)
            ->andWhere('isUsed ', '=', 0)
            ->andWhere('ExpDate ', '>', '2019-09-05')  
 ;

 $second = DB::table('your_table')
             ->select('your_table.*')
            ->where('UserID ', '=', 1)
            ->andWhere('isUsed', '=', 0)
            ->whereNull('ExpDate') 

            ->union($first)
            ->get();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be confusing coming from SQL, but you'll need two `orWhere` in Eloquent to achieve this. So basically:

```
Hak::orWhereNull('ExpDate')
        ->orWhere('ExpDate', '>', '2019-09-05')
        ->where('UserID', 23)
        ->get()
```

EDIT: Haven't tested it though, but you might need a subquery to filter the userId as well.

Comment: This gets all rows from table, not filter UserID. Thanks for helping